# Is there a way to improve the performance of Hibernate-generated queries when stored functions are involved?

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate, stored-functions

I have a page which shows some records in a grid in a paged manner. I have the table `my_table` and the entity `MyTable` linked to it:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="my_table")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class MyTable extends BaseEntity implements Auditable, Serializable {
    //...
    private Integer myAttribute; //This does not exist in the table
    //...
    @Formula(value = "(myFunction(attr1, attr2))")
    public Integer getMyAttribute() {
        return myAttribute;
    }

    public void setMyAttribute(Integer myAttribute) {
        this.myAttribute = myAttribute;
    }
    //...
}
```

When I intend to query by "normal" fields, everything works greatly, but when I attempt to filter by `myAttribute`, like:

```
queryInput.addAndCriterion(Restrictions.eq("myAttribute", v));
```

where for instance `v` is an `Integer` with the value of 123, the search will time out. If I run the stored function in MySQL directly, then it is executed instantly. I think this code sends a separate request on each item, which could explain the problem. Is there a way to ensure that I can filter by my stored function in a performant way (maybe the call for the stored function will be generated into the query)? I would need to define a criteria which specifies that for each record a certain stored function needs to be called and `attr1` and `attr2` are passed, which are fields of the records?

Comment: Are you even allowed to query on non-persistent fields? Turn on SQL logging and see what is going on. I would consider defining a DB view with the calculated field. Rather than using `@Formula` you can then use JPA `@SecondaryTable` to have the field populated from this view and can search/sort as for any other field.

Comment: @AlanHay thank you for your comment. It seems to be a potential solution. I will consider creating a view if that's allowed. I will need to see whether I am allowed to call stored functions.

Comment: You mentioned in comments what query you would like Hibernate to generate. You should find out what query it is actually generating instead. You can look in `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` while it's executing if you're quick enough, or else you can `SET GLOBAL general_log=ON;` and watch for the query in the query log in the MySQL server (remember to turn the log off afterwards).

Comment: @AlanHay if I search for a disjunction, where criteria1 is something quick and criteria2 is depending on a formula, then the search is executed quickly and well, so the issue is timeout.

Comment: First, show us what the generated SQL looks like.  We can help you improve that.  (But of course, you have to work backward to figure out how to get Hibernate to achieve the new code.)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment below, this answer doesn't fix the problem of troubleshooting Hibernate, but the OP liked it anyway.

Answer follows...

---

Querying on any function, a stored function or a builtin function, is always a table-scan.

For example this would not be able to use an index on `create_date`, even if one existed:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MONTH(create_date) = 2
```

The same is true anytime you use an indexed column as arguments to a function.

The workaround for MySQL 5.7 and later is to use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) for that expression, and then index the generated column.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
  ADD COLUMN created_month INT AS (MONTH(create_date)),
  ADD INDEX (created_month);
```

Once you do that, you can query for `created_month = 2` or you can even query the original expression `MONTH(create_date) = 2` and it will use the index.

Unfortunately, you can use this feature only with builtin MySQL functions.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html says:

> Generated column expressions must adhere to the following rules. An error occurs if an expression contains disallowed constructs.
>
> - Stored functions and user-defined functions are not permitted.

An alternative solution would be for you to create a new concrete column to store the result of the stored function, supposing the value is deterministic from its arguments and doesn't depend on the state of data in other tables.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
  ADD COLUMN myAttribute INT,
  ADD INDEX (myAttribute);

CREATE TRIGGER att_ins BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.myAttribute = MyFunction(NEW.attr1, NEW.attr2);

CREATE TRIGGER att_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON MyTable 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.myAttribute = MyFunction(NEW.attr1, NEW.attr2);
```

Then you would query the new column instead of the expression.

That's kind of a hassle, but it's the only way to get an indexed lookup against the result of your stored function.

Comment: I have tested with selection from the given table by the stored function limit 0, 25 (instant) or limit 0, 1000, executed in 2.49 seconds. The problem is not with the stored function itself. If I manually write the query, it is fast. The problem is that when I do it via Hibernate, it is very very slow in comparison to the query I would like it to generate. I would like Hibernate to generate a query like select c1, ..., cn from my_table where myFunction(attr1, attr2); Adding a column to this table is an undesirable option, as my_table has many columns and records already and the value changes.

Comment: I mean the value changes very frequently. So, I have my_table, which will have a stored function in the where clause, which will depend on myFunction. myFunction depends on my_other_table and my_yet_another_table, both of which are much smaller than my_table and can be queried quickly. Generated columns are not an option either, as you accurately pointed out.

Comment: "That's kind of a hassle, but it's the only way to get an indexed lookup against the result of your stored function." My problem is that I'm not able to generate the query I would like (due to my very limited knowledge about Hibernate), indexed lookup at this point is not needed. In the future if the actual query will become slow as well, I will need to look for alternative solutions, but at this point if Hibernate could generate the query I need it would solve my problem. As a result, this answer does not solve the problem, but it is a high quality answer and deserves an upvote.